# reuse VB(A) code across multiple Office applications

Tags: vba

We are using different Office applications (Excel, Word, Powerpoint, Access, Visio) in versions between 2003 and 2010. I have a simple task which is the same in each of these application, namely creating a filename based on a couple of parameters to pick from a dialog box.

Sofar I have created a `Function getStructuredFilename() as String` displaying a (modal) form with some buttons and text boxes, returning a string, for each individual Office application in its own VBA environment and stored them in template files used with each of these applications - meaning I have to maintain the same piece of code for each of the Office applications seperately.

This brings with it that (eg. Excel) all files created on the basis of that template do "contain macro's" which some of my users find disturbing.

I wonder if there is a way of defining the dialog form once and call it from each of the office applications - like an "external reference", an ActiveX, whatever ...

Any ideas?

Comment: Exporting as a .bas file per Zaider's suggestion will make it easier to include the same code in each template but still leaves you with the problem of templates that include code.  The other suggestion, creating a plugin (in Office they're called add-ins) is probably the way to go.  Add-ins can add buttons to toolbars/ribbons and can load when Office apps load, automatically; once loaded, they're available as long as the app is active, not necessarily limited to documents based on a particular template.

Comment: Add-ins and forms are really different between Excel and Access for instance and I do not see a universal kind of plugin that would not involve macros either. Maybe an .exe that could be called from a button and that would load the appropriate file could do the job ? But then you are free to write that in any language/tool you want/like.

Comment: fuzzy lookup function: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/195635-fuzzy-matching-new-version-plus-explanation.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From within the VBA editor you can export your module as a .bas file which will allow you to import your completed code without having to redo it every time.

Alternatively have you looked into creating a plugin for office?  These may be of use to you.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa166223%28v=office.10%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507643.aspx

Comment: thanks for this, definitely worth exploring more; +1 for now, maybe this will be the selected answer in some days ... could it be that the author of the 1st article mixed up Excel VBA editor with VSTO editor ?? there is no File/New Addin in *Excel VBA*

Comment: Hmm, I haven't ever seen an option like that although it seems you can save your entire excel file as an adding type.  This link appears to have more details.  [Step by Step Instructions](http://fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut03.htm).